There is nothing to be done. What's the meaning of the sentence?

There is nothing to be done.

What's the meaning of the sentence?
There is no work that we should do? Or, there is nothing done yet?

As always, the meaning depends on context. It could mean that all preparations have been completed, so nothing remains that requires doing. Or it could mean that nothing that anyone could do would suffice (to remedy or change a situation).

Where did you read this? Please cite the source IN the question. Answers will be  opinion-based unless context is given, which might lead to closing the question.

No, not "nothing done yet".

Although context will inform it, "nothing anyone can do to help this problematic situation" is a much more common meaning than "no tasks left to accomplish."

to be seen and to be done are infinitival passive constructions.
Compare:

It remains to be seen.

It has not yet been seen.  It remains, i.e. it stays in the state, of not having been seen.  In other words, we must wait to see what happens.

It remains to be seen whether this experimental treatment will succeed.

Or:

There is nothing to be seen here.

Nothing is to be seen here.  If you look, you will see nothing (i.e. nothing of interest, nothing worth looking at).

Move along. There is nothing to be seen here. Just a couple of frat boys puking.

Or:

There's nothing to be done.

No action is required:

Sit down and relax. There's nothing to be done.

No action would be useful or efficacious:

We've tried every treatment. I'm sorry, but there's nothing to be done.

